# Using PHP to format word documents(.doc/.docx) files

Tags: php

Here, i'm developing an job portal application, where job seekers will and upload their resumes.
other side employers will view job seekers resumes online.
for that i'm reading word document using php.
But it is displaying as unformatted text.
How can i format it.

**below is code i'm using to read word document.**

```
<?php
    function read_file_docx($filename){

        $striped_content = '';
        $content = '';

        if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

        $zip = zip_open($filename);

        if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;


        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

            if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

            $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }// end while

        zip_close($zip);

        //echo $content;
        //echo "<hr>";
        file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);       

        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', "\r\n", $content);
        $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
        $content = str_replace("\t",'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$content);
            //$striped_content = strip_tags($content);


        return $content;
    }



    $filename = "document.docx";

    $content = read_file_docx($filename);
    if($content !== false) {
        echo "<hr>";
        echo nl2br($content);
        echo "<hr>";    
    }
    else {
        echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';
    }
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: hi dude did you got the result

Comment: superb dude..please post it as answer